# Allow only HTTPS enabled sites to use my javascript and css

Tags: javascript, http, https

My site is HTTPS enabled and shares some modules with external world i.e. plugins. I wants to enable only HTTPS sites to render my plugin and deny rendering to HTTP sites.

Suggest me if its possible to implement.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible, but would have to be done serverside by just letting the `https` protocol work etc. it can't be done in clientside javascript, meaning you'll have to be more specific about how, and with what, you're serving the files.

Comment: it is possible to filter the request from server side by checking the protocol of the request URL, but it will depend on your server side technology.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (location.protocol.toLowerCase() !== "https") {
  console.log("This plugin does not support http");
}
else { ... }
```